# How can we store history for image or content files in chat room in quickblox iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, quickblox, chatroom

I am new to iOS and developing a chat application.I was able to integrated the quickblox in iOS,But i am facing an issue i am unable to store the history for files,content in the chat room.Is there possible to see the history of the files like chat messages?

If anyone have idea.Please reply.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to persist data in iOS:

1. NSUserDefaults
2. plist
3. CoreData

Option 3 is most likely the one you are looking for. This is [a great tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.But the exact issue is that suppose i share files in group by me then i can store.But someone share files to group then must be visible to me in history.Have you got the exact issue?

Comment: You can just percist the file in CoreData

Comment: You have tagged the question with parse.com. You need to create the history yourself, i.e. in an Activity class like in the Parse.com Anypic app (where Activity is used to track when people comment or like a picture). You can use the same approach to store an "activity" like "User X added the file 'xyz.zip' to the chatroom". There is no built-in functionality for this. You have to create it all yourself.